# Show that Minkowski functional is a sublinear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

A set $C\subseteq X$ is **convex** if for any $x,y\in C$ and any $0\leq t \leq 1,$ we have $tx+(1-t)y\in C.$

A set $C\subseteq X$ is **absorbing** if for any $x\in X,$ there exists $t>0$ such that $tx\in C.$

Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $C$ be a convex and absorbing subset of $X.$
Define $\rho:X\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$\rho(x) = \inf\{t>0: \frac{x}{t}\in C \}.$$
Show that

> (a) $\rho$ is well-defined and that $\rho(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in X.$
>
> (b) $\rho(ax) = a\rho(x)$ for any $x\in X$ and any $a\geq 0.$
>
> (c) $\rho(x+y) \leq \rho(x)+\rho(y)$ for any $x,y\in X.$
>
> Moreover,
> $$\{x\in X:\rho(x)<1 \} \subseteq C \subseteq \{ x\in X:\rho(x)\leq 1\}.$$

My attempt:

**part (a):** Fix $x\in X.$ Clearly $\{t>0:\frac{x}{t}\in C\}$ is bounded below by $0.$ Since $C$ is absorbing, there exists $t>0$ such that
$$tx = \frac{x}{\frac{1}{t}} \in C.$$
Therefore, the set $\{t>0:\frac{x}{t}\in C \}\neq \emptyset$ and hence $\rho$ is well-defined.

Fix $\varepsilon>0.$ Then there exists $t>0$ such that $\frac{x}{t}\in C$ and
$$\rho(x) +\varepsilon>t>0.$$
Since $\varepsilon >0$ is arbitrary, therefore $\rho(x)\geq 0.$

**part (b):** Fix $x\in X$ Clearly $\rho(ax)=a\rho(x)$ holds if $a=0$ as $\rho(0)= 0.$
Assume that $\alpha>0.$
Then
$$\rho(ax) = \inf\{a\frac{t}{a} : \frac{ax}{t} = \frac{x}{\frac{t}{a}} \in C\} = a\inf\{\frac{t}{a}: \frac{x}{\frac{t}{a}}\in C \} = a\rho(x).$$

**part (c):** Fix $\varepsilon>0.$
Then there exist $t_x$ and $t_y$ such that $\frac{x}{t_x} \in C, \frac{y}{t_y}\in C,$
$$t_x<\rho(x)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \text{ and } t_y < \rho(y) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
It follows that
$$t_x+t_y < \rho(x) + \rho(y) + \varepsilon.$$
By convexity of $C,$
$$\frac{x+y}{t_x+t_y} = (\frac{t_x}{t_x+t_y})\frac{x}{t_x} + (\frac{t_y}{t_x+t_y})\frac{y}{t_y} \in C.$$
Therefore,
$$\rho(x+y) \leq t_x+t_y < \rho(x)+\rho(y)+\varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, hence
$$\rho(x+y)\leq \rho(x)+\rho(y).$$

**'Moreover' part:**
Let $x\in \{x\in X:\rho(x)<1\}.$
Let $\varepsilon = 1 - \rho(x)>0.$
Then there exists $t>0$ such that $\frac{x}{t}\in C$ and
$$1 = \rho(x)+\varepsilon > t.$$
Note that If $C$ is absorbing, then $0\in C.$
By convexity of $C,$
$$x = t(\frac{x}{t}) + (1-t)0\in C.$$

Finally, let $x\in C.$
Then $\frac{x}{1} = x \in C.$
Therefore, $\rho(x)\leq 1.$

Are my proofs correct?

Comment: I see nothing wrong. About the only suggestion I have is that for the last part of (a), it probably would be okay to simply say that since every $t \in \{t > 0 : \frac xt \in C\}$ is $\ge 0$, it must be that their infimum is also $\ge 0$. Since this exercise is not about infimums and supremums, you should be able to make use of their basic properties without having to demonstrate them from the definition. But that is a suggestion for clarifying, not a problem with the proof.

Comment: Your definition of absorbing set is right if the set $C$ is convex (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Absorbing_set&oldid=926509425#Properties)). It may a typo; just put here to avoid misunderstanding the definition.